# Photoshop quick export is saving wrong size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, creative-cloud, save

I'm trying to export a simple document using File > Export > Quick export as PNG. It's a banner with 240x400 but Photoshop is exporting with dimensions 212x400, so it is reducing width and I have no idea why. I never had seen something like that before.

I have a snapshot with a description about what's going on but I don't know how to fix it. See here:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea? Is there some reported bug about?

Comment: Are you trying to resize it within this export window?  Seems like the program is doing a pretty decent job of telling you the problem right there.  The dimensions the original image were created at cannot be exactly matched, keeping the same aspect ratio, to the ones you are entering

Comment: I tried to resize, but Photoshop wasn't allowing me. So, after posting on Adobe forums, I got this message: "The exported png is cropping to the actual pixels in the image, not the canvas size. When you export the image, choose which is most important to you, either the width or the height. The other dimension will be done automatically based on the proportions of the art. If the exported png has to be exactly 240 x 400, then you need to fill the canvas so that there aren't any transparent areas around the edge." I didn't understand very well but if it's right, let's follow it.

Comment: Whatever, thanks for your help! Stack Exchange is really awesome for us when we have a problem.

Comment: Just to note: after I deleted the white background and used a fill layer to take all space in background, sounds like that problem was gone and I could export like a charm. I have no idea why it happened considering we have a background and we suppose that a background has the function of filling the whole canvas. But ok, let's continue the game!